# How to change default path of Celery beat service?

Tags: python, celery

I installed `Celery` as a Windows service. My code moves *.pid and Celery log files into another directory, but three files (`celerybeat-schedule.bak`, `celerybeat-schedule.dir`, `celerybeat-schedule.dat`) which I am not able to move.
I used below code for changing other file's default path:

```
command = '"{celery_path}" -A {proj_dir} beat -f "{log_path}" -l info --pidfile="{pid_path}" '.format(
celery_path=os.path.join(PYTHONSCRIPTPATH, 'celery.exe'),
proj_dir=PROJECTDIR,
# log_path_1=os.path.join(INSTDIR,'celery_2.log')),
log_path=os.path.join(tmpdir,'celery_'+cur_date_time+'.log'),
pid_path = os.path.join(tmpdir,'celerybeat_'+cur_date_time+'.pid'))
```

How to change default path of Celery beat service?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you executed `celery -A your.project.app beat --help` it would print you very useful CLI help where you would find the solution to your problem - the `-s <path to the scheduler database file>` flag.

```
-s SCHEDULE, --schedule SCHEDULE
                      Path to the schedule database. Defaults to celerybeat-
                      schedule. The extension '.db' may be appended to the
                      filename. Default is celerybeat-schedule.
```

All you have to do is to pass a full path to the schedule database file to your Celery beat process. Example: `-s C:/services/celery/celerybeat-schedule.db`

Comment: I have updated code as you have suggested but now getting error like "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '=D:\\production\\fe_service\\fe_services\\Celery_files\\celerybeat-schedule.dat'" .

Comment: what is that `=` doing there?

Comment: I have got line from my celery log file.
beat: Starting...
ERROR/MainProcess] Removing corrupted schedule file '=D:\\production\\fe_service\\fe_services\\Celery_files\\celerybeat-schedule': OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')
Traceback (most recent call last):
KeyError: 'scheduler'
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '=D:\\production\\fe_service\\fe_services\\Celery_files\\celerybeat-schedule.dat'

Comment: It was from log file.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that Celery was never supposed to run on Windows (as far as I know).

Answer (score 6):

Finally I am able to change path of celery services using below code.

```
command = '"{celery_path}" -A {proj_dir} beat -f "{log_path}" -l info --pidfile="{pid_path}" '.format(
            celery_path=os.path.join(PYTHONSCRIPTPATH, 'celery.exe'),
            proj_dir=PROJECTDIR,
            # log_path_1=os.path.join(INSTDIR,'celery_2.log')),
            log_path=os.path.join(CELERYDIR,'celery_'+cur_date_time+'.log'),
            # bak_path=os.path.join(CELERYDIR,'celerybeat-schedule'),
            pid_path = os.path.join(CELERYDIR,'celerybeat_'+cur_date_time+'.pid'))
```